# Redimensionar imagen con Intervention Image

Tags: php, laravel, imagen, laravel-9, storage

Quería consultar porque no estoy pudiendo redimensionar las imagenes que se suben y no entiendo que parte del código está mal o que me estará faltando.
Instalé la librería de Intervention Image, lo configuré en el archivo "config/app.php"

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
],

 'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
        // 'ExampleClass' => App\Example\ExampleClass::class,
        'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
 ])->toArray(),
```

Y lo estoy usando en el controlador de la siguiente manera:

```
        if($request->hasFile('img')){

            $img = $request->file('img');
            $nombreImg = date('YmdHis') . "_" . \Str::slug($data['titulo']) . "." . $img->extension();

            $resizedImg = Image::make($request->file('img'))
                ->resize(300, 300);

            $img = $resizedImg;

            $img->storeAs('img', $nombreImg, 'public');

            $data['img'] = $nombreImg;
        }
```

Pero me lanza error: Command (StoreAs) is not available for driver (Gd).

¿Cómo puedo hacer para solucionarlo? ¿Alguien puede darme una mano con esto?

Desde ya muchas gracias

Quiero redimensionar las imágenes que se suban a través de un formulario y guardarlas con Storage.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como lo hago en una aplicación que hice:
Lo único que tienes que cambiar es la forma como redimensionas la imagen y el StoreAS por un save, pasando el path previamente recuperado.

Esta función sirve para validar si la carpeta dentro de storage está creada, de lo contrario se crea `Storage::makeDirectory('posts');`

```
   if ($request->file('file')) {
        
        $name = str_replace(" ", "", Str::random(10) . $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName());
        $path = storage_path('app/public/posts/' . $name);
        $pathRelative = 'posts/' . $name;

        Storage::makeDirectory('posts');

        $img = Image::make($request->file('file'))
            ->resize(1200, 800, function($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })
            ->save($path);

        // Guardamos la ruta de el archivo
            // Llamamos la relacion de post e image
        $post->image()->create([
            'url' => $pathRelative
        ]);
    }
```

La razón por la que no te ayudo con tu ejemplo es porque considero que le falta información y es más fácil mostrándote un ejemplo funcional. Cualquier duda quedo atento. Suerte!